# How to handle migrations with multiple entity managers in DoctrineMigrationsBundle 3

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, doctrine-migrations

On `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` 2.* this was relatively simple - use the `--em` option (and use `ContainerAwareInterface` to skip any migrations from a different em/connection).

Now (on `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` 3.2.2), it seems the `--em` option is ignored, and the default em/connection is always specified, meaning the migrations for the default em are applied to every database. Edit: As pointed out in comments - `--em` is not ignored, it's passed through directly, it's rather our `ContainerAwareInterface` approach that's no longer valid.

There is a lot of conflicting information on how to set this up, some suggesting it should "just work" (Symfony Docs) and other describing workarounds (Issue):

https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html
https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/38

How does one configure this new version (3) of `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` to apply migrations only to their matching entity/db?

Edit: I've included below our config previous to upgrading, which along with the `ContainerAwareInterface` connection filtering approach, allowed filtering migrations to run only against the appropriate entity manager.

Our existing `"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "1.12.8"` config (shortened, but shows multiple entity managers):

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            default:
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                driver: '%database_driver%'
                server_version: mariadb-10.4.11
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: autotempest
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
            model:
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                driver: '%database_driver%'
                server_version: mariadb-10.4.11
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: autotempest_models
                user: '%database_user%'
                password: '%database_password%'
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
                wrapper_class: App\Doctrine\ConnectionWrapper\ConnectionModel
            persistent: true

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: '%kernel.debug%'
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                mappings:
                    App:
                        type: 'annotation'
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Entity/Main'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
            model:
                connection: model
                mappings:
                    TempestModelBundle:
                        type: 'annotation'
                        dir: 'Entity'
                        prefix: 'Tempest\Bundle\ModelBundle\Entity'
```

Our `"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "2.1.2"` config:

```
doctrine_migrations:
    dir_name: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/Migrations'
    namespace: Application\Migrations
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the configurations for your doctrine and migrations settings.

Comment: For general reference, all `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` does is [registers the commands in symfony](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/3.2.2/Resources/config/services.xml#L53) based on the classes in `doctrine/migrations`  that extends [`DoctrineCommand`](https://github.com/doctrine/migrations/blob/3.5.0/lib/Doctrine/Migrations/Tools/Console/Command/DoctrineCommand.php#L49)

Comment: @WillB. thanks, I've added our existing config. Re: what `doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle` does - it also [provides the `services` config option](https://symfony.com/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/current/index.html#:~:text=The%20services%20node%20allows%20you%20to%20provide%20custom%20services%20to%20the%20underlying%20DependencyFactory%20part%20of%20doctrine/migrations.), which we need in order to inject services into our migrations via `MigrationFactory`.

Comment: I meant in regards to creating or honoring the console command options such as  `--em`. The bundle does not override them from the `DoctrineCommand` which calls `$this->dependencyFactory->getConfiguration()->setEntityManagerName($emName);`, when the `--em` option is supplied. The bundle creates the `DependencyFactory` service passed to `DoctrineCommand` based on your [Symfony config](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/blob/3.2.2/DependencyInjection/CompilerPass/ConfigureDependencyFactoryPass.php).

Comment: Ah, thanks for the clarification. There were a couple layers to the issue, but it rested mainly on the fact that container aware migrations are no longer really a good approach to implement multiple entity manager support. We've arrived at a solution that works for us for now however.

Comment: I believe the issue is with `TempestModelBundle.mappings.dir: 'Entity'` of your `model` EntityManager since it uses the same connection user/password, as opposed to referencing the path to the absolute path of the explicit namespace `%kernel.project_dir%/src/Tempest/Bundle/ModelBundle/Entity`.

Comment: The config I posted in my question works fine in the versions I mentioned there. My problem was figuring out how to migrate it to the new versions. I've answered with the working approach we went with below (which uses the same `doctrine` config as above, just required a different approach for migrations).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also mentioned in my question, there is an open issue on the `DoctrineMigrationsBundle` from 2012 describing the problem of dealing with migrations when using multiple entity managers: https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/issues/38. It seems there are several options for workarounds to this issue as described there, we just needed to dig and try each of them to find the best one for our situation.

### Container Aware Migrations

On Symfony 3, we were using the `ContainerAwareInterface` approach. Described in the above issue:

> Currently this can be achieved by using Container Aware Migrations. If one can have the service container injected, he can obtain an instance of some entity manager and its connection.

This is no longer really a valid solution when moving to Symfony 4 however, due to `ContainerAware` classes being deprecated in favor of dependency injection.

### Pass configuration directly

Another approach mentioned in the github issue above. The idea here is to have a separate configuration file for each entity manager like the following:

```
# config/packages/migrations/base.yaml
em: default
transactional: false
migrations_paths:
    Hyra\Migrations\Base: src/Migrations/Base
table_storage:
    table_name: migration_versions
```

This is passed directly to the command, along with the entity manager like this: `bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate --em default --configuration config/packages/migrations/base.yaml`. These separate config files replace the single `config/packages/doctrine_migrations.yaml` configuration file.

This was also not viable for us, as we still needed to inject services into our migrations using the `services` configuration option of `DoctrineMigrationsBundle`, and `--configuration` only passes configuration options directly through to `doctrine/migrations`, which doesn't support the `services` configuration option.

Initially on `DoctrineMigrationsBundle` 3.0, this approach was complicated by the fact that the `--em` and `--conn` options were dropped completely, so it was also necessary to create a wrapper on top of the `DoctrineMigrationsBundle` commands to re-implement these options ([described in more detail here](https://jmsche.fr/en/blog/upgrade-doctrine-migrations-from-2-x-to-3-0)). This is no longer necessary on `DoctrineMigrationsBundle` 3.1+ (which restored these options).

### Use `DoctrineMigrationsMultipleDatabaseBundle`

Also mentioned in the github issue thread, [this bundle](https://github.com/AvaiBookSports/DoctrineMigrationsMultipleDatabaseBundle) implements what we needed exactly (and ended up using) - per-entity configuration for `DoctrineMigrationsBundle`, so we can also include our `services` config for migration dependency injection. Initially I misconfigured this - it's important that the base `doctrine_migrations.yaml` config only includes config for the default entity manager. Sample working config provided by the package author (version 0.3.3):

```
# doctrine.yaml
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                url: '%env(resolve:DATABASE_URL)%'
                server_version: mariadb-10.1.26
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string
            geonames:
                url: '%env(resolve:GEONAMES_DATABASE_URL)%'
                server_version: mariadb-10.1.26
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                mapping_types:
                    enum: string

        # IMPORTANT: You MUST configure your server version,
        # either here or in the DATABASE_URL env var (see .env file)
        #server_version: '5.7'
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: true
        default_entity_manager: default
        entity_managers:
            default:
                connection: default
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                mappings:
                    Main:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/App/Entity/Main'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Main'
                        alias: Main
            geonames:
                naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore_number_aware
                connection: geonames
                mappings:
                    Geonames:
                        is_bundle: false
                        type: annotation
                        dir: '%kernel.project_dir%/src/App/Entity/Geonames'
                        prefix: 'App\Entity\Geonames'
                        alias: Geonames
```

```
# doctrine_migrations.yaml
doctrine_migrations:
    em: default
    migrations_paths:
        DoctrineMigrations: '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/Main'
```

```
# doctrine_migrations_multiple_database.yaml
doctrine_migrations_multiple_database:
    entity_managers:
        default:
            migrations_paths:
                DoctrineMigrations\Main: '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/Main'
        geonames:
            migrations_paths:
                DoctrineMigrations\Geonames: '%kernel.project_dir%/migrations/Geonames'
```

Comment: It returns an error "In InvalidConfigurationKey.php line 16: Migrations configuration key "doctrine_migrations" does not exist."